# npm install command is not working at all why?

Tags: node.js

the error shown in the command prompt is as below:
I tried the command: **npm install**
and the error showed up as seen below.

> *npm ERR! cb() never called! npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself.

Comment: check your code and handle callback properly.

Comment: the npm install command does not work even installing a new init file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a broken npm package. Just update npm and it should work.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: Sure, why not :D Just test it